# how to enter text in Name field if its value Keep changing after each refresh?

Tags: java, selenium

I am relatively new to Java and Selenium.
URL : https://register.rediff.com/register/register.php?FormName=user_details
I want to send keys into the name field. when I am trying to find the element by name tag I am unable do so because name attributes value changed each time.

```
`<input type="text" onblur="fieldTrack(this);" name="name86b72791" value="" style="width:185px;" maxlength="61">`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well You can select this using relative xpath
`//input[starts-with(@name,'name')]`

Here **starts-with** only checks whether the name attribute starts-with **name** and ignore other randomly generated kinds of stuff.